# SQL Function call in Select Statement to populate Reporting Services Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return a specific digit for each number in a dataset, I've written an SQL function and now I need to be able to do the calculation in the function for each number in the dataset. Can you please point me in the correct direction? I don't know if I should create a temp table then join that, if I should just write a vb function within Reporting Services and do that or if I just need to start over.

Here is the function
    USE [CUDatabase]
    GO

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_Check_Digit]    Script Date: 11/13/2012    14:40:59 ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Check_Digit]
(
    @unique_NBR VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @Values TABLE
(
    check_digit int,
    unique_nbr int
)
AS

  BEGIN

  -- set up working variables
DECLARE @LEN AS INT
DECLARE @INDEX AS INT
DECLARE @CHAR AS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @POSITION AS INT
DECLARE @VALUE AS INT
DECLARE @SUBTOTAL AS INT
DECLARE @BASE AS INT
DECLARE @CHECK_DIG AS INT
SET @LEN = LEN(@MEMBER_NBR)
SET @INDEX = 1
SET @POSITION = 0
SET @VALUE = 0
SET @SUBTOTAL = 0
SET @BASE =0
SET @CHECK_DIG = 0

  -- iterate until we have no more characters to work with
  WHILE @index<=@len
BEGIN
    SET @char = SUBSTRING(@unique_NBR,(@len-@POSITION),1)
    select @value = (SELECT scd.dig_mul_value
                    FROM CUDatabase.DBO.sdcCheckDigit SCD
                    WHERE SCD.dig_place = @index)


    set @value = @value * @char
    SET @index = @index + 1
    SET @POSITION = @POSITION + 1
    SET @SUBTOTAL = @VALUE + @SUBTOTAL


END  
SET @BASE = ((@SUBTOTAL/10)+1)*10
    IF @BASE -@SUBTOTAL = 10
        SET @CHECK_DIG = 0  
    ELSE
        SET @CHECK_DIG = @BASE-@SUBTOTAL

INSERT INTO @Values (check_digit, unique_nbr) VALUES (CAST(@CHECK_DIG AS         int),@unique_NBR)

RETURN 

END    


GO
```

The table that is in the select statement of that function has the following values in it:
        dig_place   dig_mul_value
    1                7
    2                3
    3                1
    4                7
    5                3
    6                1
    7                7
    8                3
    9                1

Here is the dataset, I need to loop through each unique_nbr and return the check digit.

```
`SELECT I.D1NAME,
    IA.ADDRESS_ID,
    A.ADDRESS1,
    A.ADDRESS2,
    A.ADDRESS3,
    A.CITY,
    A.STATE,
    A.ZIP_STR,
    TL.COMPANY_NAME,
    TL.COMPANY_DESCRIPTION,
    TL.EFFECTIVE_ENTRY_DATE,
    TL.AMOUNT,
    TL.ACCOUNT_NBR,
    TL.ACCT_DBRN
FROM MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT MP 
    JOIN  INDIVIDUAL I ON
        I.INDIVIDUAL_ID = MP.INDIVIDUAL_ID
        AND I.DL_LOAD_DATE = MP.DL_LOAD_DATE
    JOIN INDIVIDUALADDRESS IA ON
        IA.INDIVIDUAL_ID = I.INDIVIDUAL_ID
        AND IA.IS_PRIMARY = 1
        AND IA.DL_LOAD_DATE = I.DL_LOAD_DATE
    JOIN ADDRESS A ON
        A.ADDRESS_ID = IA.ADDRESS_ID
        AND A.DL_LOAD_DATE = IA.DL_LOAD_DATE
    JOIN (SELECT EFT.unique_NBR,
                EFT.ACCOUNT_NBR,
                EFT.ACH_SDC_NBR,
                EFT.COMPANY_NAME,
                EFT.COMPANY_DESCRIPTION,
                EFT.INDIVIDUAL_ID_NBR,
                EFT.INDIVIDUAL_NAME,
                EFT.XPTIMESTAMP,
                EFT.STANDARD_ENTRY_CLASS,
                EFT.ROUTING_NUMBER,
                EFT.ACCT_DBRN,
                EFT.AMOUNT,
                EFT.EFFECTIVE_ENTRY_DATE
            FROM EFTTRANSACTION EFT
            WHERE EFT.ROUTING_NUMBER = 999999999
                AND EFT.STANDARD_ENTRY_CLASS IN ('WEB','TEL')
                AND EFT.EFFECTIVE_ENTRY_DATE >= '11/01/2012') TL
ON T  L.unique_NBR = MP.unique_NBR
WHERE MP.DL_LOAD_DATE = (SELECT MAX(DL_LOAD_DATE) FROM MEMBERSHIPPARTICIPANT)
    AND MP.PARTICIPATION_TYPE = 101
    --AND MP.unique_NBR = 9835
ORDER BY MP.unique_NBR`
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is call the SQL function you have already created, i.e.

```
SELECT I.D1NAME,
    IA.ADDRESS_ID,
    A.ADDRESS1,
    A.ADDRESS2,
    A.ADDRESS3,
    A.CITY,
    A.STATE,
    A.ZIP_STR,
    TL.COMPANY_NAME,
    TL.COMPANY_DESCRIPTION,
    TL.EFFECTIVE_ENTRY_DATE,
    TL.AMOUNT,
    TL.ACCOUNT_NBR,
    TL.ACCT_DBRN,
    dbo.fn_Check_Digit(L.unique_NBR) CheckDigit
FROM .....
```

Comment: When I attempt what you suggested, I get the following message Msg     4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_Check_Digit", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I needed to change my function from table to scalar, that resolved the issue!